# JavaScript failing to extract quotes css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

In my stylesheet, I define some custom quotes [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/quotes], but when I try to access them with JavaScript it gives me the default value despite it being present in the actual CSS; any thoughts would be much appreciated:

```
>> document.getElementById('-my-widget-style')
 <style id="-my-widget-style" type="text/css" media="all">...</style>

>> document.getElementById('-my-widget-style').innerHTML
 " .-my-widget-wrapper #content {
   quotes: "<<" ">>";
 }
 "

>> document.getElementById('content').style.quotes
 ""

>> $('#content').css('quotes')
 ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `style` property gets the styles set directly on the element in the style attribute.  You will only get back your custom quote property if it is set there, not from a stylesheet.

```
 <div id="content" style="quotes:...">...</div>
```

EDIT:  See comments for further discussion.  Seems like it may be an issue with webkit.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, so I was surprised when `window.getComputedStyle()` failed as well: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nVJZ7/).

Comment: @DavidThomas That is unexpected.

Comment: @JamesMontagne is there any way to access the quotes property with JavaScript if its been set via the stylesheet?

Comment: Sort of a way around it (though it feels a little untidy, albeit I *do* suspect it's the only way this'll be allowed at all): [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nVJZ7/2/).

Comment: @JamesMontagne incorrect, `.css()` retrieve computed styles not just inline, ​​​​​​​http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/hxRBs/

Comment: @Musa is this a bug in the browser(s) then? This happens to me in Chrome and Firefox's latest versions.

Comment: @zallarak for me it only fails in webkit browsers

Comment: @DavidThomas Please post yours as an answer so I can delete mine.  Since mine is wrong I'd like to delete it but don't want to lose your response.